# Is "m by zero matrix" undefined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It doesn't make sense to me just like $\frac{1}{0}$ but I don't know if it is enough to declare that it is undefined. 
I would like to know though it's not very important, i guess.

Comment: It's not very a very interesting case, but there's no reason why it can't be defined. If you're familiar with the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations of vector spaces, a $0 \times 0$ matrix would represent a linear transformation $V \to W$ where $\dim V = \dim W = 0$. Note that, in fact, this would be distinct from, say, a $2 \times 0$ matrix and a $0 \times 2$ matrix - all of these are examples of degenerate, but *distinct*, "matrices".

Comment: Related: [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring)

Comment: Miles Reid made a remark in one of his books, I think *Undergraduate commutative Algebra*, in which he (I think jokingly) mentioned something called "empty set theory" that is concerned with questions like this. Whenever questions like this roll around, I'm tempted to create that tag...

Comment: @pjs36 I like that name. Thinking about it though, it's probably best to avoid using it; like the word "trivial", it sounds a bit derogatory even though it's not intended that way.